# Eclipse RCP 4 - binding column in table and iobservable value

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-databinding

I have the following issue - I have an IObservableValue, which is changing, and should be displayed in the first column of a table. The values in the other columns are based on this value (in each other column the value is calculated and the value is dependent on the value in the first column). How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try binding to a jface viewer. The tutorial [here](http://notes-lawan.rhcloud.com/posts/JFaceViewerDataBinding) uses jface tree but it should work similarly with tables.